# remain a problem - is it correct?

Tags: verbs

I saw the sentence below:

> Accessibility remains a problem in many parts of the world.

Is it a correct sentence? Because according to dictionaries, "remain" can be used only as an intransitive verb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a grammatical sentence. Here's the relevant definition from [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/remain):

> (copulative) To continue in a state of being.
>
> > The light ***remained*** red for two full minutes.

***remain*** is equivalent to ***to continue to be*** in your sentence:

> Accessibility ***continues to be*** a problem in many parts of the world.